# Agrupar arrays com campos iguais

Tags: php

Ola pessoal tenho a seguinte representação de um array

```
    [cfop] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 1403
                    [value] => 10.50
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 1403
                    [value] => 1.50
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 2102
                    [value] => 27.60
                )

        )
```

Eu gostaria com (PHP) de agrupar e somar os valores dos campos "value" onde o campo "code" for igual, a representação final seria algo assim

```
        [cfop] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [code] => 1403
                        [value] => 12.00
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [code] => 2102
                        [value] => 27.60
                    )

            )
```

Eu tentei isso

```
            if($event['cfop']){

                $cfops       = [];

                foreach($event['cfop'] as $item){

                    $exist = false;

                    foreach($cfops as &$cfop){

                        if($item['code'] == $cfop['code']){

                            $exist = true;

                            $cfop['value'] += $item['value'];

                        }
                    }

                    if(!$exist) $cfops[] = $item;
                }

                $event['cfop'] = $cfops;

                unset($cfops); 
            }
```

mas não deu certo, ele acaba duplicando alguns itens do aray

Comment: Poderia colocar na pergunta o que tentou fazer e qual foi o resultado obtido?

Comment: O que eu preciso é agrupar os itens de cada array onde o campo 'code' se repete, e no momento de agrupar eu preciso somar os valores dentro do campo 'value'

Comment: Sim, isso ficou claro; o que não ficou claro é a sua dificuldade. Você tentou fazer antes de perguntar? Se sim, poderia descrever sua tentativa e o resultado que obteve? Se não, tente; pode começar pelo básico, tal como percorrendo o *array* e utilizando condições para ver quando somar.

Comment: eu tentei vários codigos, que encontrei em outras perguntas aqui do stack, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: A forma mais simples seria algo como: https://ideone.com/eX22cm

Comment: Obrigado rray, fiz algumas modificações no codigo de exemplo que passou e deu certo aqui.